# Bacula daemon not listening properly

Tags: linux, backup

I set Bacula up a few days ago, and everything seemed fine. I noticed today that jobs were failing, and upon investigation, it looks like `bacula-sd` is just not listening on the port it should be listening on. The daemon is running, but `netstat -nlap | grep bacula` turns up nothing.

It worked fine before, and nothing really changed as far as I know. I tried `strace`ing it as it started, but nothing jumped out. It hasn't written anything to, or even created, `/var/log/bacula/log`. How can I make `bacula-sd` start listening?

Comment: Being sick sucks. I retyped your chat conversation for you. FYI there was a place where you said "nestat" and I assumed you meant "netstat" and changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the director running on a different machine? Since you didn't see the director or file daemon show up when you ran netstat I'm thinking that the service isn't running. If for some reason the daemons fail to run I would run each of the daemons from the command line with the -t and -c switches to check the config files for errors.

```
bacula-sd -t -c [path the bacula-sd.conf]
bacula-fd -t -c [path the bacula-fd.conf]
bacula-dir -t -c [path the bacula-dir.conf]
```

Comment: The director and fd are running on a different machine. Only the sd runs on this machine, and it is definitely running, but not listening.

Comment: I'm thinking at this point you might need to start bacula-sd from the command line with the -f switch and maybe some others (-d ##, -v) to run it in the foreground and look for any issues. You may also want to check if something else is using port 9103.